# Is a decision based form action possible

Tags: html, forms, jsp, action

so I have something I am trying to figure out how to go about doing.

I have a form like so created on a JSP page.

```
<form:form method="post" action="/home" commandName="detailsDto" enctype="multipart/form-data">

//display form stuff here

    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td >
            <input type="submit" id="stSave" class="button button_save pointer" value=""/>

            <button id="stCancel" class="button button_cancel pointer"></button>
        </td>
    </tr>

</form:form>
```

I need a third button that is "save and return" which will take you to a different page if clicked.

```
<input type="submit" id="stSaveAndReturn" class="button button_save_and_return pointer" value=""/>
```

but is there a way to have the form action change upon which save button I click?

As in instead of directing to /home have it direct to /profile or whatever I want.

or do I need to go about it a different way

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try diffrent actions based on JS request if possible? Then call diffrent API method if clicked button 1st, diffrent for 2nd and so on